# html2pdf does previous job every time

Tags: php, pdf, session-variables, html2pdf

I have a script which is generating a PDF out of html page. I use `html2pdf` to achieve this. When I run my code one of the session variables (which is responsible for multiplying the number of pages) is cleaned before it gets to the PDF and when I run it second time it finds the variable and it generates the right amount of pages but for the previous process (although this time I gave different number to the lbl textbox in form). I think it is something to do with the buffer when I use `html2pdf` but I do not know how to overcome this problem. Also is it possible to overwrite the same PDF as I have to force to delete it before generating new PDF?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['lbl'])) {
    $file = 'test.pdf';

    if(file_exists($file)){
        unlink('test.pdf');
    }

    include(root . '/barcodeGen.php');
    include(root . '/pdfGen.php');

    $labelNo = $_POST['lbl'];
    $_SESSION['labelNo'] = $labelNo;      //this variable is cleaned before it gets to labels.php (which is html page that is converted to pdf)
}
?>
```

pdfGen.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
include(root .'/labels.php');

$content = ob_get_clean();

// convert to PDF
require_once(root . '/html2pdf.class.php');
try {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', '150x200', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(2, 2, 2, 2));
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');       
}
catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
?>
```

part of labels.php

```
<?php

 $uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
 $qcode = $_SESSION['qcode'];
 $quantity = $_SESSION['quantity'];
 $start_date = $_SESSION['date'];
 $barcode = $_SESSION['barcode'];
 $labelNo = $_SESSION['labelNo'];
 echo $labelNo;
?>
```

the error is: 
Notice: Undefined index: labelNo in C:\wamp\www\dev\labels.php on line 8

Comment: You said that the session variable gets cleaned, can you show us that code?

Comment: I added the code the first time I enter number to lbl (that textbox) (for example 8) and run the code it says: `Notice: Undefined index: labelNo in C:\wamp\www\dev\labels.php on line 8` . When I refresh the page / resubmit it with empty textbox it finds the lbl but does the process for that 8 and not for new value after that it does the previous value I gave.

Comment: Why are you using `$_SESSION`s in the first place?

Comment: does it matter? I have multiple clients accessing the the same set of pages shared printers and they only raspberry Pi, I need to pass a lot of data here and there and I found SESSION to be most reliable for me. If you want to propose the solution using POST or COOKIE then feel free to do so, I will adjust my code.

Comment: Well, it does matter, actually :) `$_SESSION` stores values in the user's session throughout multiple requests which is a good way to manage things like logins, but not so great for managing request-driven functionality. I think if you refactored your code to not use sessions, you might fix your problem. Also, where are these `$_SESSION` values getting set?

Comment: Across different pages. First page is login then I'm processing barcode then another form and then displaying pdf and generating number of labels given by user. every page has its own unique variables and certain pages need to use them. I'm novice at php but it is easier for me to use SESSION variables